# Agreement of the adverb "tout" with the number of the adjective that follows it

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, adverbes, adjectifs-indefinis, tout-tous

It's written on the website pasted below that when **tout** modifies a feminine adjective beginning with a consonant sound or an aspirated h, it must take the form **toute** irrespective of whether the adjective is singular or plural.
https://french.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/tout-tous-and-toute-toutes-all-all-of-them-the-whole-indefinite-pronouns

Hence, it translates *Elles sont toutes joyeuses* as "They are all merry" (**toutes** used as a pronoun) and *Elles sont toute joyeuses* as "They're very merry" (**toute** used as an adverb).
However, the following website states that **tout** has to agree both in gender and number with the feminine adjective (beginning with a consonant or an aspirated h) that follows it. And it translates *Elles sont toutes petites* as "They're very small".
https://www.fluentu.com/blog/french/tout-vs-tous/

So, which one is correct? I don't think both of them can be acceptable.

Comment: The first website also says that the adverb agrees in the feminine plural. Maybe check again? No disagreement there!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The plural agreement is expected in that case:

> Elles sont **toutes** joyeuses.

so there is no way to sort out:

> Toutes sont joyeuses

and

> Elles sont bien joyeuses.

Reference: https://bescherelle.ca/adverbe-tout/